# Asserting on session variable set in controller - Grails test case

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit

I have a controller action that checks a condition and based on the condition's result, it will set a field to session variable

Controller:

```
def checkUser={
    if(condition: true){
       session.user = id
    }else{
       session.user=null
    }
}
```

Now, in my testcase, if I have to assert on this session's user value, how do i do it?

I tried it like this, but it did not work:

```
void testSomething(){
    controller.checkUser()
    assertNull(session.user)
}
```

Any idea on how to assert session variable which is being set in the controller?

Comment: assertions are by default not enabled in Java. You need to explicitly enable them using -ea (or) -enableassertion parameters.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself but when accessing the params I know you can do controller.params.  What happens if you do assertNull(controller.session.user) ??

Comment: conroller.session.user does not work. It throws and exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your test class extends *ControllerUnitTestCase* or is using the test Mixin.

CUTC offers several mocks to facilitate Controller testing. Here's what you'll do:

```
void testSomething(){
    controller.checkUser()
    assertNull(mockSession.user)
}
```

- Here's the doc: http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/api/grails/test/ControllerUnitTestCase.html
- If you're using grails 2.0+: http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/test/MvcUnitTestCase.html